# How to produce JSON object to Kafka without using kafka's JsonSerializer

Tags: json, apache-kafka, serialization

I have a spring boot web service that consumes XML files , producing JSON to the MQ, however I have had a difficult time unmarshalling the XMLs due to the  tags in the XSD schema and subsequent XMLElementRef objects they create. As a workaround, I made a custom JAXB element serializer that's used by the ObjectMapper to convert these XML to JSON.

The issue arises in that the configuration for Kafka requires a serializer. `config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, null);` does not work nor does the JsonSerializer while the string serializer escapes all the `"` to `\"`which makes for consuming these messages quite a headache.

How would I go about producing these JSON objects? Is there a simple serializer configuration for kafka?

Comment: If your strings are getting escaped strings and quotes , something else is wrong with your code. Kafka isn't putting those there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing something like `config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, null)` will never work, you need to tell Kafka how to treat objects you provide.

You can explicitly serialize your own data to byte array and then push byte array with your own serializer implementation.

You'd need to implement `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer` interface, where the most interesting method would look somewhat like this:

```
@Override
byte[] serialize(String topic, YourXmlClass data) {
    return data.toByteArray(); // or something richer
}
```

And then you'd configure producer via `config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, YourSerializerClass.class)`

Obviously, you'll need the deserializer as well on consumer side.